# Python: Determine assigned serial port my hardware connected to

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, microcontroller, pyserial

Microcontroller interfacing with Windows PC via USB CDC creating virtual serial port. Windows assign port number randomly depend on availability, USB port and differs from computer to computer. The question is how via Python script determine which port assigned for my microcontroller and use it.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and how it failed, and Stackoverflow will try to help you. Asking how to program a Python script (show me the code) is not encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ctypes to figure out which ports are available

you can connect to each port that is available and send something like `get ver` where you know the expected response.

when you find expected response you have found your serialport

alternatively (and probably easier) you can just enumerate through all 256 comports (0-255) and try/except to connect to them

```
for i in range(256):
    try:
       s = serial.Serial(i)
       print "Found A Serial Port Available At COM%d"%i
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
       print "Nothing On COM%d"%i
```